# Can I build on cases within a switch statement in Objective C?

Tags: switch-statement

I am somewhat new to programming in general. Even more so with Objective-C. I am trying to display labels and text boxes based on a value entered on a previous screen. Here is what I currently have:

```
switch (previousValue) {
   case 1:
      [label1 setHidden:FALSE];
      [textField1 setHidden:FALSE];
      break;

   case 2:
      [label1 setHidden:FALSE];
      [textField1 setHidden:FALSE];
      [label2 setHidden:FALSE];
      [textField2 setHidden:FALSE];
      break;

   case n:
      [label1 setHidden:FALSE];
      [textField1 setHidden:FALSE];
      [label2 setHidden:FALSE];
      [textField2 setHidden:FALSE];
      [labelN setHidden:FALSE];
      [textFieldN setHidden:FALSE];
      break;
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this? I have 60 possible cases. I am also using a switch statement in a similar fashion, but it deals with calculations that build upon each other. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should put your labels and textFields in an array and just iterate over them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're IBOutlets you could set up IBOutletCollections which will create an array of the outlets you want to organize. Then you could simply call:

```
[_outlets setValue:@NO forKeyPath:@"hidden"];
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have N<=60 labels/textfileds and you set for each one hidden:False  according to a value. Using a switch statement like that increases your code size and it's not very readable. 
A better way is to use a bitFiled: each bit in the bitfield corresponds to one label/textfield - bit3 is used for label3/textField3.

Let's assume you only have 8 labels/textfields - you just need to choose a bigger data type for more bits - and see how you would code that:

```
char Bitfield;

int mask =0x01;
for( i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    if (bitfield&mask)
    {
     setHidden(i); // sets the attributes for label/textfield i
    }
   mask>>=1;
}
```

Aside from the fact that the code becomes more readable, now you have control over each label/textfield individually -  you can set the attributes only for label/textfields 1 and 5, if you wisht to.